# Check value outside of class changed in Jest test

Tags: jestjs

I've got the following file I want to test with Jest, but I'm not sure how I can check that the value of `someVar` changed from `true` to `false`. To clarify, `someVar` is in the same file, but outside the `class`

```
let someVar = true

class SomeClass() {
  clear() {
    someVar = false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'd love to know if it's possible to test the scenario I've described, I discovered that it's super easy to test if I just write my code better. Here's an example

```
class SomeClass() {
  constructor() {
    this._someVar = false;
  }
  get someVar() { return this._someVar; }
  set someVar(value) { this._someVar = value; }
  clear() {
    this.someVar = false;
  }
}

describe('SomeClass', () => {
  it('sets someVar to false', () => {
    const someClass = new SomeClass();
    someClass.someVar = true;
    someClass.clear();
    expect(someClass.someVar).toEqual(false);
  });
})
```